# Can you have two or more types defined in different indexes for the same entity?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I’m using Elasticsearch 0.9 with FOSElasticaBundle 3.0.0.alpha6 and Symfony 2.5.10.
Will FOSElastica Listener keep all indexes updated? Can I define different listener services for each environment? I'm asking to see if I can use different indexes for the production, development and test environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will FOSElastica Listener keep all indexes updated

Yes, if you will configure `persistence` section properly in your config file.

> Can I define different listener services for each environment? I'm asking to see if I can use different indexes for the production, development and test environments.

If I understand you well, the solution for that is [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/setup.md#c-basic-bundle-configuration).
You can just set other index name in each environment's config (prod, dev, test).

Or even better, you can use `kernel.env` parameter to dynamically change used indexes depending on current environment:

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_elastica:
    indexes:
        app:
            index_name: app_%kernel.env%
```

Comment: Thanks Dragoste, I found the relevant docs a few minutes ago. This should definitely do what I need to do for the test environment. In order to use the same index for prod and dev would i just add aliases of index_prod and index_dev to my main index?